Ansible: How to reset the ansible_python_interpreter variable in the middle of the playbook
In a data center environment (Hetzner), hosts can be network-booted into a so-called "rescue system" where the initial OS imaging and rescue operation can be done. The same host can then be booted (back) into the regular system. I'm successfully using Ansible to do that, booting back and forth.
However, it seems Ansible is carrying the ansible_python_interpreter variable over across reboots and reconnects. As it happens, the two systems do not have exactly the same Python version.
How can I reset the ansible_python_interpreter back to 'auto_silent' variable after the reboot? The following does not work:
    - name: Reboot the server
      ansible.builtin.reboot:

    - name: Install Python on the new system
      # Note, this needs to be done raw (chicken & egg)
      ansible.builtin.raw: apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y python3-minimal
      changed_when: true

    # it seems ansible_python_interpreter is not rediscovered in ansible.builtin.setup,
    # but carried over from the rescue system, which might be different.
    - name: Reset the Python interpreter
      ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        ansible_python_interpreter: auto_silent # DOES NOT WORK

    - name: Gather facts
      ansible.builtin.setup:


I guess I can globally set the ansible_python_interpreter to '/usr/bin/python3' but that seems to subterfuge the automatism inside Ansible.

In a Hetzner environment with Debian VMs I've just used additionally raw: 'ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python' ...
